# How to extend Microsoft Reserved partition

Tags: windows-update, windows-11, diskpart, system-reserved-partition, windows-11-v22h2

I cannot receive Windows 11 feature updates, specifically Windows 11 version 22H2.

1. I tried joining the Windows Insider Programme initially on the Release Preview channel, but this still did not list any new updates.
2. I then switched to the Beta channel which did list a Windows 11 Insider Preview, but on trying to install it I receive an error (0x8024a205):

> "We couldn’t update system reserved partition."

3. I looked at Disk Management, but only have options to view properties for the `(C:)` Volume and not the other 2: `EFI System Partition` and `Recovery Partition`; there was no `Reserved Partition` displayed.
4. So, I used `diskpart` in a `cmd` Terminal (with administrator rights) and was able to see 4 partitions:

```
 Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    System             100 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    Reserved            16 MB   101 MB
  Partition 3    Primary            475 GB   117 MB
  Partition 4    Recovery           611 MB   476 GB
```

However, attempting to extend the Reserved partition like so:

```
cmd prompt

>diskpart
>list disk
>select disk 0
>list partition
>select partition 2
>extend size=112
```

I am prevented as `Reserved Partition` is not a volume so can't be extended. Attempting to extend the `System Partition` is also prevented.

**Is it possible for me to A) increase the size of the `Reserved Partition`, or B) free up space on it?**

All I'd like to do is get the new (now old) Windows update, is there a mechanism to achieve this (preferably without losing all my files)?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/-we-couldn-t-update-system-reserved-partition-error-installing-windows-10-46865f3f-37bb-4c51-c69f-07271b6672ac far too much to precis here.

Comment: The article is fairly technical. You might be better off to back everything up to a USB Drive and then reinstall Windows and let it create partitions properly. Then  it should update.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you, this worked. However, it is painful that there is no way modify the sizes of these partitions. I'm now locked in to relying that periodically deleting those files will still allow me to install updates.

Comment: @John So, installing Windows will re-do the partitions making them appropriate sizes? From where can I install Windows 11, I'm guessing I should look for an ISO that I can put onto a USB and then boot from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows is pretty stupid about that.

Cleanest way is to reinstall, but open command prompt before choosing the disk to install windows to, and run diskpart and just create those partition yourself, with extra space, like 512mb for reserved and 512 for efi

Or even 1gb if you plan to dual boot.
Then just click on the refresh button and choose the main one you did.

Messy way is to use AOMEI partition assitant, but you'll be able to resize the EFI one (by making unallocated space by shriking main partition and moving it to the end of the disk), by making sure the unallocated space is right after the efi partition.
But for the reserved parition, I can't make it resize it, because it's type is "other", what a pain

You can reclaim some space by following this :
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/-we-couldn-t-update-system-reserved-partition-error-installing-windows-10-46865f3f-37bb-4c51-c69f-07271b6672ac

not sure it will be enough though

Comment: Thanks. After successfully installing the Windows 11 update in original post, I'm finding with each major update it breaks the OS in some way, requiring me to system restore, clean and attempt to update again. I guess this is due to inappropriately sized partitions. The latest update (at time of this comment) 23H2, broke the OS so much that restore was insufficient, and I had to reset the PC keeping files re-installing Windows from internet. However, in Disk Management the sizes of the partitions were the same as before. Does installing from USB installation media correct partitions?